# flutter google sign in issue

Tags: firebase, flutter

I make an app with using flutter and firebase. I want to fix my google login with showing profile image and it's name. I used this code to authenticate with google.

```
 void _handleSubmitted(String text){
      _textController.clear();
      _googleSignIn.signIn().then((user){
        var message = {
          'sender': {'name': user.displayName, 'imageUrl': user.photoUrl},
          'text': text
        };
      });
     // _addMessage(name: user.displayName, text: text);
      var user;
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
              name: user.displayName,
              text: text,
              senderImageUrl: user.photoUrl
      );
      setState(() {
          _message.insert(0, message);  
        });
  }
```

then I used this method to view login image and name using this code, but this code not showing my image or nothing. It shows me error.

```
child: new GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
                  ChatMessage.sender.imageUrl,
                  ChatMessage.sender.name

                 //child: new Text(name[0]),

                ),
```

Comment: Any error messages in the console log output?

Comment: displayName not found

Comment: "displayName not found" is not much information. Is there more?

Comment: I/flutter ( 6722): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 6722): The getter 'displayName' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6722): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6722): Tried calling: displayName
I/flutter ( 6722): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Comment: if you want full code i can send you

Comment: No, I don't want the full code. The question should contain the code that allows to reproduce. I don't even know if I can help you. If you add the required info to your questions other might spot the issue and be able to help.